# Function to get type of the value entered in a textbox

Tags: c#

Just for fun, I tried creating a function that takes the value entered in a textbox, and determines the type of it. Below is the full code.

```
 public string GetType(string inputValue)
    {
        //Variables for the parse result
        //Can be discarded. Used because parse function mandates output variable
        int intParseResult;
        decimal decimalParseResult;
        bool boolParseResult;

        //Parse for different datatypes and check the output
        if (int.TryParse(inputValue, out intParseResult))
        {
            return typeof(int).Name;
        }
        if (decimal.TryParse(inputValue, out decimalParseResult))
        {
            return typeof(decimal).Name;
        }
        if (bool.TryParse(inputValue, out boolParseResult))
        {
            return typeof(bool).Name;
        }
        //If all parse fails, return string type.
        return typeof(string).Name;
    }
```

Since the text property is a string, I am trying to parse the input into different types, and returning the type name based on it.

As of now, I see two quick issues. One is that it will need one if condition for each data type. Second is that function is creating variables and discarding them unnecessarily.

I am looking for suggestions on how to improve this code. Again, this code is created just for fun, so no urgency. I will just like to see different possible ways to improve the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For improved maintainability, you can create a List of the types you want to check against.

By creating your own TryParse method you can iterate through the types until you get a valid type.

For the TryParse method the Convert class has a ChangeType method that works for any Object to any valid Type.  Putting this in a `try/catch` block will allow the same basic operation as the various TryParse methods.

I prefer a static class for something like this:

```
public class GetStringBaseType
{
    static List<Type> types = new List<Type>()
    {
        typeof(UInt16),
        typeof(UInt32),
        typeof(UInt64),
        typeof(Int16),
        typeof(Int32),
        typeof(Int64),
        typeof(Single),
        typeof(Double),
        typeof(Decimal),
        typeof(Boolean)
    };

    public static Type GetBaseType(string value)
    {
        foreach(var t in types)
        {
            if(TryParse(value,t))
            {
                return t;
            }
        }
        return typeof(string);
    }
    static bool TryParse(string value, Type baseType)
    {
        try
        {
            Convert.ChangeType(value, baseType);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

By changing the order of the types in the list you can show a preference for specific types, for certain values that may convert to different types.

Since people get their nose bent out of shape using `try/catch` this way, I came up with an alternative version.  This one is obviously more verbose, and uses the `TypeCode` enum instead of the `Type`.  Also since the enum collection can't be modified, I've included an overload that accepts a `List<TypeCode>` to restrict searching for only certain types:

```
public class GetStringBaseType
{


    public static TypeCode GetBaseType(string value)
    {
        foreach (var v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TypeCode)))
        {
            TypeCode tc = (TypeCode)v;
            if (TryParse(value, (TypeCode)tc))
            {
                return tc;
            }
        }
        return TypeCode.String;
    }
    public static TypeCode GetBaseType(string value, List<TypeCode> typeList)
    {
        foreach (var tc in typeList)
        {
            if (TryParse(value, tc))
            {
                return tc;
            }
        }
        return TypeCode.String;
    }
    static bool TryParse(string value, TypeCode baseType)
    {
        switch (baseType)
        {
            case TypeCode.Boolean:
                return Boolean.TryParse(value,out _);

            case TypeCode.Byte:
                return Byte.TryParse(value, out _);

            case TypeCode.Char:
                return Char.TryParse(value, out _);

            case TypeCode.DateTime:
                return DateTime.TryParse(value, out _);

            case TypeCode.Decimal:
                return Decimal.TryParse(value, out _);

            case TypeCode.Double:
                return Double.TryParse(value, out _);

            case TypeCode.Int16:
                return Int16.TryParse(value, out _);

            case TypeCode.Int32:
                return Int32.TryParse(value, out _);

            case TypeCode.Int64:
                return Int64.TryParse(value, out _);

            case TypeCode.SByte:
                return SByte.TryParse(value, out _);

            case TypeCode.Single:
                return Single.TryParse(value, out _);

            case TypeCode.UInt16:
                return UInt16.TryParse(value, out _);

            case TypeCode.UInt32:
                return UInt32.TryParse(value, out _);

            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                return UInt64.TryParse(value, out _);

            case TypeCode.DBNull:
                return value == DBNull.Value.ToString();

            case TypeCode.Empty:
                return value == String.Empty || value == null;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The main change is the `TryParse` which uses a `switch` block to check against every type.

Comment: `GetBaseType` could have 2nd parameter to have optional list of types to check in given user specified order.  If the list is null, you could default to `types` property.

Comment: @RickDavin - true

Comment: TryParse with an exception handler, this is a big NO. The whole point of having it is performance and to avoid exceptions. Your implementation is the opposite of that.

Comment: @t3chb0t -    >As of now, I see two quick issues. One is that it will need one if condition for each data type. Second is that function is creating variables and discarding them unnecessarily.   This addresses the main concerns of the OP.  Depending on preferences sometimes sacrifices in other areas might need to be made.  Coding is in many ways about flexibility not hard coded ideas that can't be changed or adapted.  Unless millions of strings and or millions of characters are being used the hit on performance will be negligible.

Comment: That second style is perfect for me. It does everything I need. I will probably not need to pass type code list, so, I can skip that function. Other than that, I think It is perfect for my use. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's what you can do:

- Since you are not using the `out var` variable you can remove them altogether and use the discard character which is the underscore to just ignore them `_`.
- I usually prefer to use `{}` in `if`s but this method is so short and all conditions are so similar that I'd make them one-liners.
- Don't call the parameter `inputValue` but simply `value`. It might be an *input* outside but inside this method *input* has no meaning. The value can come from any source.
- Don't return a `string` but let the user of this method do with the `Type` whatever he likes or call this method `GetTypeName` so its purpose is clear.

Example:

```
public Type GetType(string value)
{
    if (int.TryParse(value, out _)) return typeof(int);
    if (decimal.TryParse(value, out _)) return typeof(decimal);
    if (bool.TryParse(value, out _)) return typeof(bool);

    //If all parse fails, return string type.
    return typeof(string);
}
```

Comment: Silly that the discard still requires `var`, but alas, far better than the original in my opinion.

Comment: @202_accepted actually `var`s are not required; I've just tried it out and it works without `var` too so I removed them :-o

Comment: Awesome, that's great to see!

Comment: Awesome. I honestly had no idea about `_`. That should change a lot.

Comment: Apparently, this doesn't work below c# 7. :/

Answer (score 3):

Building upon the great answer by @t3chb0t ... you will have to check individual `if`'s because a `switch` is insufficient for the variety of choices.  My answer is more for future maintenance for a given control or perhaps you will have different checks for another control, perhaps skip the bool check and replace decimal with double.  If your needs will ever be along those lines, add a class of quick extension methods:

```
public static class IsTypeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsInt32(this string value) => int.TryParse(value, out _);
    public static bool IsDecimal(this string value) => decimal.TryParse(value, out _);
    public static bool IsBool(this string value) => bool.TryParse(value, out _);
    // You may add more in the future:
    public static bool IsInt64(this string value) => long.TryParse(value, out _);
    public static bool IsDouble(this string value) => double.TryParse(value, out _);
}
```

So the `GetType` would become:

```
public Type GetType(string value)
{
    if (value.IsInt32()) return typeof(int);
    if (value.IsInt64()) return typeof(long);
    if (value.IsDecimal()) return typeof(decimal);
    if (value.IsBool()) return typeof(bool);

    //If all parse fails, return string type.
    return typeof(string);
}
```

This offers somewhat more flexibility for future modifications, and I find it slightly more readable.  The downside is that now `GetType` is no longer self-contained.

Comment: One could go really crazy and decorate the extensions with special attributes for the types and retrieve them via reflection so that they're more closely related to the actual extensions ;-]